# What is the tension on a string with unbalanced forces on each side?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram, string

If a string is pulling on an object of mass $M_1$ with force $F_1$, and the other side is pulling an object of mass $M_2$ with force $F_2$, what is the tension in the rope?

Intuitively, it makes sense to me that the tension in the rope would be the sum of the forces which it exerts (and thus is exerted on it), and so the tension would be $F_1 + F_2$.

Answer (score 1):

If an inextensible  string is massless, and with unbalenced forces, it is accelerating *infinitely fast*. If it is inextensible, but not *exactly* massless with  total mass $m$,  then the acceleration at every point on the string is is $(F_1-F_2)/m$ and the tension is $F_1$ at the $F_1$  end,  and $F_2$ at the $F_2$ end. The exact value of the tension at intermediaate points   along the string depends on the density profile along  the string.

Comment: The string can't be accelerating infinitely fast; there are non-massless objects on either side.

Comment: The string only cares about the forces on *it*. In $F=ma$ it is the external forces is  $F_1-F_2$. What part of this do you not understand?

Comment: The fact that it is impossible for the string to accelerate infinitely if the things it is attached to cannot?

Comment: So we conclude that  the things that it is attached to *cannot* apply different forces at the ends -- as was said right at the begining.

Comment: i don't see why not. perhaps there's a tension force, or an electromagnetic force, pulling on those, which exerts tension force onto the rope.